# System stop responding and throws yami i/o error

Tags: c++

I need suggestion about YAMI library . I have a system which receives Json string from external interface and parse that received string and send that message to internal ip address for the required action. 
The exchange of messages within the internal ip address has been taken care by Yami library. everything works fine but occasionally  it displays yam i/o error and system doesn't response  unless it is restarted.
The whole software is written in C++ and C  and development os is fedora 11.

I have tried to investigate the problem but I am bit clueless as I have not found much  help on internet and my testing method doesn't work.

its strange that system works for few hours and then crash . For example If  I leave system idle for half an hour and then try to send message via external interface it crashes producing yami i/o error  or even while sending continuos command it crashes.

Any help or suggestion will be of great help.

Thanks and regards,
Sam

Comment: Are there any more details about the error/exception you can provide? Copying the message exactly in your question is generally helpful.

Comment: I have debug statement in my code and its exactly like "Yami:i/o error"

Comment: nothing more or less i can find in log

Comment: You're going to have to narrow down where and when the error occurs. Ideally you'd run it under a debugger until the error occurs and you can look at the call stack. There is the agent::register_io_error_logger (http://www.inspirel.com/yami4/doc/cpp/classyami_1_1agent.html#a2768b563f95f90aab00e59b1c9d1a029) which I haven't used but might be useful. Adding additional logging to a file may also be useful.

Comment: Thanks usep , I will look into it and update you guys..

Comment: Hi Guys , I have looked into the code and  found that yami::agent variable is declared as private in base class and there is base class function say RegisterwithServer which uses the yami::agent variable to register and publish  teh service. Now this function( RegisterwithServer) is called by derived class in the constructor). On looking into code use debug statement I have found it failed to go into base clas constructor and derived class constructor. Do you guys think  I need to initilasie yami::agent in  base class ? I have similar sort of link below

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9810858/failed-to-create-object-of-derived-class-in-some-cases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this exception is from a `core::io_error` result which is translated to a runtime exception by `details::translate_result_to_exception()`. Most of this error originates from the source code in yami/posix in your case.

What you have to do now is figure out where the error originates and ultimately the source of the issue. You should be able to get a rough idea from what happens in your code when the error occurs (are you creating a new connection, sending data, receiving data, etc...).

If that doesn't yield any obvious results I would probably create a test project using the yami source code instead of the library file so I would be able to trace into the yami code to  where the error originates from.