# Failed to create object of derived class in some cases

Tags: c++

```
// Base Class    
class Base
{
   public:
     void RegisterWithServer();
     // some more functions
   protected:
      Base(std::string aTestName, std::string aServerName);
      ~Base();

   private:    
          std::string mString;
          std::string mServerName;
          yami::agent mYAMIAgent;     
  };


 // Base Class constructor

     Base::Base(string aTargetName, string aServerName):
     mString(aTargetName),
     mServerName(aServerName)
    {
        // my debug statment
         cout <<" we are in Base Class constructor"<< std::endl;
        cout <<" in normal case we get this debug statement  but in case of crash  it doesnt  reach till here I suppose "<< endl;
     }


 // DerivedClass
  class derivedClient: public Base
  {
     public:

      derivedClient(std::string aceptedString);
      virtual ~derivedClient();

     private:
        std::string mServerAddress;
        std::string mServerName;
   };


// constructor
 derivedClient::derivedClient(string aceptedString):
 Base(aceptedString, "ServerTest"),
 mServerAddress(aceptedString),
 mServerName ("ServerTest")
 {
        cout <<" in normal case we get this debug statement  but in case of crash it doesnt  reach till here I suppose "<< endl;

 RegisterWithServer(); // call base class function
};


 // in some other  function in different file

 some function()
{
    .....
   .....
   try
   {
    if( meet certain condition)
    {
         ......
         ......
          cout <<" the code reached till here" << std::endl;
         derivedClient dClient("192.168.2.110");// problem ??

          cout <<"in case of crash below lines are not printed nor any message is printed from both constructors "<< std::endl;

       }
    }

   catch( const yami::yami_logic_error & aYamiException)
   {
    cout << "error: " << aYamiException.what() << endl;
    }

}
```

Hi Guys,
I am fixing the bug in the existing software .
Problem -> after some times the software stops responding .
What I have  done ->  I have traced the problem and found that when software crashes it fails before the object creation from dervived class.

The derived class calls  dervived constructor and base constructor. I have added debug statement and found nothing is printed on debug.

I want to know  why the code is not even going into derived class and base class ? is it possible that private variables have not been initialsed  properly ?

Please throw some comments on sample code.
Thanks and regards,
Sam

Comment: `RegisterWithServer()` - Looks suspicious.

Comment: The problem is almost certainly something to do with `yami::agent`.  This will be constructed before the body of `Base::Base` or `derivedClient::derivedClient` is run.

Comment: RegisterWithServer() when called from derived constructor  creats yamiagent. example                                                             //register the subscription for incoming messages
    mYAMIAgent.register_object(mServerrName + ".Subscriber", *this);

Comment: in case of crash , it doesnt reach till RegisterWithServer(0 function

Comment: @samantha: `mYAMIAgent` is a member variable of the base class; all member variables are initialised (i.e. have their constructors called) *before* your constructor body is run.

Comment: @Oli, you mean , i have to initialised the mYamiAgent before calling any constructors? if That is the case then do you think it shouldnt work at all? The above code works most of the time but occasionally it broke down. My knowledge is bit limited in C++. Sorry if my question sounds silly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm would guess that the constructor for `yami::agent` throws an exception which is why all the couts are not being run. As Oli mentioned in the comments all member variables of a class will be constructed before the class constructor is entered so `yami::agent::agent()` will be run before `Base::Base()` is entered.

Edit:

If you have something like:

```
class MyObject
{
     yami::agent m_Agent;    
public:
     MyObject::MyObject() { }
};
```

then m_Agent will get constructed using its default constructor which is declared as `agent(const parameters & options = parameters());`. As you mention, for some reason yami::agent::agent() throws an exception which could due to any number of reasons such as a network initialization error, invalid input parameters, etc....

If you want to specify custom parameters to the yami::agent constructor you can do something like:

```
 yami::parameters& GetDefaultYamiOptions (void)
 {
      static yami::parameters options;

            /* The following are just some example parameters */
      options.set_integer(yami::option_names::connection_retries, 1);
      options.set_integer(yami::option_names::connection_retry_delay_spread, 10);
      options.set_integer(yami::option_names::tcp_nonblocking, true);
      options.set_integer(yami::option_names::file_nonblocking, true);
      options.set_integer(yami::option_names::tcp_connect_timeout, 1000);

      return options;
 }

 class MyObject
 {
      yami::agent m_Agent;    
 public:

     MyObject::MyObject() : m_Agent(GetDefaultYamiOptions())
     {
     }
 };
```

What parameters you need may be different than what I use and the cause of the issue may not be even related to incorrect parameters. It could well be a low level networking error from the OS or even hardware.

Comment: Thanks usep for the help ..
 yami::agent client_agent; if I use above line in my code in private part of Base class wont it create default constructor of agent with default value?

ANd if my above method is wrong , then how and where should I create constructor for Yami::agent(). 

Thanks ..